# Antiforgerytoken in postdata of jqgrid, MVC c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, antiforgerytoken

I am trying to implement antiforgery token for jqgrid,   below is what I am trying to do

```
    var token =  $('[name= "__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()

 $("#gridname").jqGrid('setGridParam',{ postData:{__RequestVerificationToken:token,aID : @ViewBag.AID}});     

 $("#gridname").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

I have also placed the @Html.AntiForgeryToken(); in the body of the page. Using debugger I can see that a token is generated too but I am getting

> **Exception Details: System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.**

in the controller, I have placed [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] and its not hitting the same. Is there any solution to this. Can Antiforgery token be applied in jqgrid?

Comment: Did you tried sending the forgery token as a header?

Comment: Try passing the value directly in postData:  __RequestVerificationToken:$('[name= "__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()

Or you try passing it in extra param of jqGrid:

extraparam : { __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()} }

Answer (score 1):

You have to add request forgery token in your HEADERS as Nacho suggested in comments.

```
var headers = {};

headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = $('[name= "__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

 $("#gridname").jqGrid('setGridParam',{ headers: headers, postData:{aID : @ViewBag.AID}});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried passing in headers like you mentioned but I am still getting System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid. Is there anything else you see I can try.